# How to remove the dynamically ng-hide class in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image][image]I have to implement the image upload functionality and the problem

```html
<div class="container responsiveImageSet">
  <div ng-show="imageLoader" style="text-align: center;">
    <img class="imageLoaderGif" src="images/googleLoader.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="container" >
      <span ng-repeat="imgURL in backgroundImageURL track by $index">
        <img class="uploadedImageSet" src="{{imgURL}}">
      </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

is that i have show the spinner before the image is uploaded and i am using ng-show for it but in the element section dynamically class="ng-hide" is added i have to remove this class becasue class is creating a problem for me please tell me how to fix this problem?

```js
$scope.backgroundImageURL = [];
$scope.imageLoader = false;
$scope.uploadBackgroundImage = function(event) {
  $scope.imageLoader = true;

  //Get the value from the input field and assign into the fireabse node
  var userProductImg = $("#imgId")[0].files[0];
  var PSR = firebase.storage().ref('user/image');

  //get the date as well as put the imageURL from node
  var rn = new Date().getTime().toString();
  var task = PSR.child(rn).put(userProductImg).then(function(snapshot) {
    $timeout(function(){
      $scope.backgroundImageURL.push(snapshot.downloadURL);
      $scope.imageLoader = false;
      localStorage.setItem('userImageURL', $scope.backgroundImageURL);
    }, 0);
  })
}
```

Comment: Not sure how your html has that ng-hide class. Checked in a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/35318/  It doesnt contain any nghide class.
can you please create a fiddle to explain it?

Answer (score 2):

I would certainly choose a `ng-if` over `ng-show` here.

[`ng-show`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow):

> The element is shown or hidden by removing or adding the .ng-hide CSS
>   class onto the element. The .ng-hide CSS class is predefined in
>   AngularJS and sets the display style to none (using an !important
>   flag).

[`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) :

> The ngIf directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree
>   based on an {expression}. If the expression assigned to ngIf evaluates
>   to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a
>   clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM.

Remember to actually use an expression :

```html
<div ng-if="imageLoader == true" style="text-align: center;">
  <img class="imageLoaderGif" src="images/googleLoader.gif">
</div>
```

You get rid of `.ng-hide` and have more accurate control, besides the element is inserted and removed when needed, not just shown or hidden by a ridiculous `!important` hack.

Comment: Sir,  imagLoader == true its not properly work for me every time condition is commented in the element section?

Comment: Hey @kapilsoni, I am not sure I understand, what do you mean by "*every time condition is commented in the element section*"? Btw you wrote `imagLoader == true`, guess it is a typo :)

Comment: Sir check updated fiddle i have uploaded image in which check imagLoader == true condition?

Comment: @kapilsoni, where is the fiddle? As I can see from the screenshot `uploadBackgroundImage()` is called when the user select a file/image. In that you set `imageLoader = true` and `imageLoader = false` when the image is saved. That should work, looks OK. Does the spinner not show up? BTW, regarding "*every time condition is commented in the element section*" Yes, all those angular directives write comments in the code.

Comment: @kapilsoni, see here, it really works by just setting a scope variable true or false -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/5kLUWWVcWkTMAU35zSpN?p=preview**

Comment: Now, its works for me.thank you sir for  this imformation regarding to the hide and show concept.